# creating own vpn services with Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I tried several VPN providers for surfing the Internet, like StrongVPN or HotspotVPN,
I`m interested can I have my own VPN services for surfing the internet,
it is possible to create my own VPN with Google Cloud?

I have pc-workstation with hardware firewall(sonicwall)
My questions is it possible to setting up Site-to-Site VPN between my hardware firewall (SonicWall NSA 240) and Google Cloud hardware firewall ?

I want that all my internet traffic from my pc go through Google Cloud 
via VPN (site-to-site) and is it possible to use Google Cloud as proxy?

I'm sincerely hope that you'll help me,Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There was a session at Google I/O 2013 that demonstrates how to leverage the routing capabilities of Google Compute Engine, and as part of the talk demonstrates how to establish a VPN connection between a premise network and the google compute environment.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=fsOiXJxcYAY

Also, see the GCE documentation for network routing:

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing

Once the tunnel is established, you could certainly then setup a proxy in the compute instance to handle your browsing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Google's own Jigsaw team recently released an open source tool that makes hosting your own VPN really simple.

https://getoutline.org/en/home